# Find all lines first point in radius 500 meter

Tags: postgis, sql, distance

I need to find all lines startPoint and lines attribut in a given radius of (0.5 km) from a point(X,Y) Then i need to find the disnace from the point(X,Y) to all of the startpoint in the given radius (0.5 km). Can someone give me a hint how to do this.

(You have to forgive me for my bad english)

Comment: Don't forget to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.